# Pseudo - High Gravity Training

Tags: weights, weighttraining

I was wondering if wearing weights during your daily life work as a *pseudo-high gravity training*.

Consider, I wear leg weights, weights on my back and arms, and wear them throughout the day *(not while sleeping, since it would be uncomfortable)*.

Now after a few months the weights seem to have become a normal part of my body, so I remove the weights now I guess I would feel very light similar to how it would feel when going to a place with a less gravity than the Earth.

***Now, is my assumption correct? Or there is something I am unaware of?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly asserted, the body adapts to stressors put on it. Remove those stressors and the body reduces its expenditure. In relation to your question, yes. However, much the way that wearing a rucksack for a long hike gives you a small (10 minute) period of relief after taking it off your bodies compensation period would be also small.

The body is good at adapting to get good at what it is doing. However, it works both ways. People that stop working out don't stay strong.

I would not recommend doing this for two reasons. Firstly, high gravity does not feel the same as strapping weights to yourself. Secondly, wearing weights are part of normal life puts a lot of sudden force on your joints. You will get joint pain doing this.